# Ways to convert a PDF file into byte array..(for flushing out using outputstream())

Tags: java, file, file-io, arrays

- Is there any other way to convert a file (PDF) into byte array other than using **FileInputStream** or **toByteArray(InputStream input)**..
- Is there any method to convert it directly. I found **Files.readAllBytes** in java.nio.file.* package but it gives **ClassNotFoundException** in my RAD. I am having Java 8 JDK in my system.
- Is java.nio.file.* package not available in Java 8?
- My requirement is that i should not to **stream** the file using InputStram.

Comment: What do you mean by *My requirement is that i should not to stream the file using InputStream*? Looks like you're confusing streaming a file by sending the file for downloading or to send its data through the net.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : Ultimately, i should send the file for downloading. The problem is that the application is crashing because of too much memory taken by the InputStream (thousands of users). This is the reason i want to skip the Input Streaming.

Comment: You cannot skip it, but seems that you're trying to load the file entirely in a `byte[]` and then send this to the output stream. This seems to be your real problem. It would be better if you provide how you read the file and store it in your output stream.

Comment: By the way, `Files#readAllBytes` uses an `InputStream` behind the scenes.

Comment: That is informative..Initially, i used the **FileInputStream** to read the **entire** PDF file as you said. Now, I have a change request for this and i am working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're loading the whole content of your file into a `byte[]` directly in memory, then writing this in the OutputStream. The problem with this approach is that if you load files of 1 or 2 GBs entirely in memory then you will encounter with `OutOfMemoryError` quickly. To avoid this, you should read the data from `InputStream` in small chunks and write these chunks in the output stream. Here's an example for file downloading:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
    new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/folder", "file.pdf")));
ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
//to make it easier to change to 8 or 16 KBs
//make some tests to determine the best performance for your case
int FILE_CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;
byte[] chunk = new byte[FILE_CHUNK_SIZE];
int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = bis.read(chunk)) != -1) {
    outStream.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
}
bis.close();
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have to deploy and do some performance testing to see if this works..